# Support for older ROS distros in 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I know that currently only Fuerte is support in Ubuntu 12.04.  Will there ever be support for Electric and the older ROS distributions in 12.04 and beyond for people who want to run legacy code?

Thank you,

Jenny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44499/support-for-older-ros-distros-in-12.04/) by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2012-09-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2012-09-24**:
Thanks, I wanted to know this too. I had problems with electric on 12.04 and switched back too 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no plans for supporting older distributions on Ubuntu 12.04 or later. See [rep-0003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1